# How to prevent layout component loading before page component in nextjs 13 new app directory?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, layout, state, next.js13

In my project there is a layout for home page. The problem is the layout component is loading before other component of home page. The layout load first and then page content is loading. how to load layout and page content at the same time?

I am expecting to load both layout and page content load at a time. not before or after one another.

`App/layout.js`

```
import Footer from "./footer";
import "./globals.css";
import NavBar from "./navbar";



export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <section>
          <NavBar />
          <div>{children}</div>
          <Footer />
        </section>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

`App/page.js`

```
"use client";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Carousel from "./home/carousel/page";
import Video from "./home/video/page";
import Gallery from "./home/gallery/page";
import Givenft from "./home/givenft/page";
import Support from "./home/support/page";

export default function Home() {
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false); 

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoaded(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {isLoaded && (
        <>
          <Carousel />
          <Video />
          <Gallery />
          <Givenft />
          <Support />
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

`I used state here to load content on the ui when all content are being fetched from server. otherwise it's loading asynchronusly. Now i need to load layout when page content are ready. not before or after`

Comment: The new `loading.jsx/tsx` might be useful here. https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/loading-ui

Comment: I don't understand, if you want all of your content to be displayed after the data has been loaded why don't you just use SSR?